# Parse decimal, but only if it uses only decimal point

Tags: c#, decimal

Is it possible to tell C# to parse a string to a decimal, but only do this successful when the string only contains a dot (or none, but no comma etc.)? Or would I have to use a regex on the string input to validate this condition?

```
// should be parsed and is parsed successfully as 1.0
var test1 = decimal.Parse("1.0", new NumberFormatInfo() { NumberDecimalSeparator = "." });
// should throw an error, but is parsed as 10
var test2 = decimal.Parse("1,0", new NumberFormatInfo() { NumberDecimalSeparator = "." });
```

Comment: Why not use [Decimal.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=net-7.0)?

Comment: @DenisMicheal.k Becaus if `Decimal.Parse` doesn't throw an error, also `Decimal.TryParse` won't return `false` ...

Comment: Oh yeah my bad hadn't seen the comment  `// should throw an error, but is parsed as 10`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the overload of [`decimal.Parse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.parse?view=net-7.0#system-decimal-parse(system-string-system-globalization-numberstyles-system-iformatprovider)) that allows a [`NumberStyles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?view=net-7.0) parameter to do this:

```
var test2 = decimal.Parse(
    "1,0", 
    NumberStyles.Number & ~NumberStyles.AllowThousands,
    new NumberFormatInfo { NumberDecimalSeparator = "." }
);
```

This will throw an exception. Or you can do the same with `TryParse()` and check the return value, to avoid having to handle an exception.

Note that `NumberStyles.Number & ~NumberStyles.AllowThousands` will allow all `Number` styles except for `AllowThousands`. You can adjust this to suit your needs if this is not exactly what you want.

For example, you might also want to exclude `AllowTrailingSign` and `AllowTrailingWhite` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, the default value of `NumberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSeparator` is set to `,` (at least in your currently used locale), and the default `NumberStyle` in `decimal.Parse` allows number groups (ie thousands, millions, ... separator). Thus, during parsing all instances of `,` are just ignored. You can see this if you do

```
var s = "1f0";
var d = decimal.Parse(s, new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo{ NumberGroupSeparator = "f"});
```

it will also parse the string to a value of `10` ...

If so by doing

```
var d = decimal.Parse(s, new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo{ NumberGroupSeparator = "", NumberDecimalSeparator = "."});
```

it will accept `.` as decimal separator but throw an error if your string contains a comma. But it will parse the string with all other default `NumberStyle` options still in place. (for instance `AllowDecimalPoint` or `AllowLeadingSign` or `AllowLeadingWhite`)

Answer (score 1):

To add some meat to Matthew Watson's answer, the reason that `"1,0"` is parsed as `10`, is because the comma is classed as a "thousands separator".

`Decimal.Parse` does not enforce that the thousands separator is in the conventional position (e.g. 1,000), so it basically strips it out, and leaves 10 in your example.

To make the comma cause an exception, then you need to *omit* `NumberStyles.AllowThousands` as a flag.

One way to do this is to allow only `NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint`, but there are other combinations that may be desirable for you, as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.parse?view=net-7.0#system-decimal-parse(system-string-system-globalization-numberstyles)).

Comment: Or you can keep the default `NumberStyle` options in parsing by using the `Parse(string, IFormatProvider)` overload setting the `NumberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSeparator = ""` so the `,` will no longer be accepted